Run a gradle task to Avro Tools
I want to create a gradle task to invoke the avro-tools-1.12.0.jar responsible to create the JAVA file based on Kafka Schema for registry.
Today I need to manually call the lib as below:
My manual command:
java -jar C:\Users\ADM\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.avro\avro-tools\1.12.0\6284f370acde9a345902705f1641222c430208b5\avro-tools-1.12.0.jar compile schema .\src\main\avro\Employee.avsc .\src\main\java\

My build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

sourceCompatibility = 21
targetCompatibility = 21

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
}

configurations {
    scheduleRuntime
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.apache.avro', name: 'avro', version: '1.12.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.avro', name: 'avro-tools', version: '1.12.0'
    implementation group: 'io.confluent', name: 'kafka-avro-serializer', version: '7.7.1'

}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'com.edu.sample.Main'
}


First, let's isolate the Avro Tools JAR rather than the unreliable approach of picking it up from the Gradle cache. We can do this is in a Gradle configuration separate from those used for the main compilation:
configurations {
    avroTools {
        transitive = false // So we pick up only the primary JAR and not its dependencies
    }
}

dependencies {
    avroTools group: 'org.apache.avro', name: 'avro-tools', version: '1.12.0'
}

Second, let's define an output directory for the generated code which is separate from the main source directory (which should be reserved for human-written source), and ensure the Java compilation picks it up:
def avroGeneratedDir = layout.buildDirectory.dir("avroGenerated")
sourceSets.main.java.srcDir(avroGeneratedDir)

Finally we can write our Gradle task which is the invocation of a JVM process by using the JavaExec task type.
tasks.register("avroCompileSchema", JavaExec) {
    classpath(configurations.avroTools) // Use the executable JAR from the new configuration
    args( // Specify the arguments of the JVM process
        "compile",
        "schema",
        "src\main\avro\Employee.avsc",
        avroGeneratedDir.get().asFile.canonicalPath
    )
}

Further improvements to this would involve:

specifying the avro source as an input of the avroCompileSchema task

making the Java compilation depend on the avroCompileSchema task, which is best done by making the code generation directory an output of that task
(Together, these would ensure that the Java compilation would be forced to re-run in the event of a modification of one of the .avro schema inputs)

Tidying all this code up into a Gradle plugin, making it available for potential re-use and avoid having it distract in the build script



Great, thanks a lot @Simon, it worked for me

Nice! In that case I'd appreciate it if you could upvote and accept the answer :)
